# Is there a way to transfer binary file to ASCII in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, binary

In my application, I am using basic-ftp package to grab files from a server. The file contains data that is in binary format. The server team showed me they had a method to line by line transfer data from binary format to ASCII.
I tried to search for an equivalent method in JavaScript but could find one. Only one similar is btoa().
Does anyone familiar with such function?

I have found btoa() so far.

Comment: "*they had a method to line by line transfer data from binary format to ASCII*" - well what does that method do exactly?

Comment: Why do you not want to transfer the file as binary directly?

Comment: What format is the binary data? Knowing the format can help you deserialize the data from binary to ASCII

Comment: Different binary format for representing data have different specifications for how the data is represented. [See this Wikipedia article for more info.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_data-serialization_formats#Comparison_of_binary_formats)

Comment: @ChukwujiobiCanon It doesn't sound like the OP has structured data serialised to a binary file, and want to deserialise it. Rather, they have an arbitrary binary file encoded to ASCII for some reason.

Comment: Base64 - encodes sets of 3 binary bytes in 4 ASCII characters.  hex format - convert 1 byte into 2 ASCII using the characters 0-9, A-F.   Please edit your question to include more details if that doesn't answer it.

Comment: @DaveS it doesn’t seem like the OP knows what format the binary data is in. Like Bergi mentions, the data might be arbitrary to them. Maybe only the backend team knows what the data is structured as.